# Type Error sub-setting a list of strings - Python 3

Tags: python, subset

I am trying to subset a list from another list, but I am getting a `TypeError`.

```
a = ('one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'three', 'three', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten')
a = list(a)
b = ('two', 'three', 'eight', 'nine')
b = list(b)
c = [a[i] for i in b]  # subsets list a for what's in list b
```

Return:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

What I'm looking for:

```
print(a)
('two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'eight', 'nine')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get items from `a` that are in `b`:

```
c = [i for i in a if i in b]
print(c)
```

**Output:**

```
['two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'eight', 'nine']
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to do that like:

#### Code:

```
filter(lambda x: x in b, a)
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = ('one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
     'three', 'three', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten')
b = {'two', 'three', 'eight', 'nine'}

print(list(filter(lambda x: x in b, a)))
```

#### Results:

```
['two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'eight', 'nine']
```